# NSArray is empty in iOS despite mysql entry

Tags: php, ios, xml, nsarray

I have been trying to fill an array in Xcode with xml output from a php script so that ios can connect to mysql. However, I keep getting an empty value for my array despite the fact that there is information in mysql. That must mean that either my attribute section or my parsing of the xml is wrong, but I really don't know what it is that actually is wrong (and no amount of starring at it seems to help). I am not getting any errors from php or xcode. Any ideas?

**EDIT: I have followed the suggestions below and I am still getting an empty value, although I believe that it is coming from my php...**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    char *cStr = "YES";
    NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cStr];


    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(censored)", _login];

    NSXMLParser *Parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
    [Parser setDelegate:self];
    [Parser parse];


NSDictionary *itemAtIndex =(NSDictionary *)[oneam objectAtIndex:0];
  oneam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   
    if (([[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"its"]isEqualToString:str3 ])) {
            [switch1 setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
            [switch1 setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"location"]) {
        [oneam addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict]];
    NSLog(@"The array is %@", oneam);
    }
}
```

And here is my php...

```
<?php

$login = "hello";
$dbh = new PDO('(censored)');
$sql = "SELECT oneam FROM login WHERE username = '$login'";

$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$r = $doc->createElement( "oneam" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );
foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $e = $doc->createElement( "location" );

    $e->setAttribute( 'its', $row['oneam']);

    $r->appendChild( $e );

}
print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Unless you have a requirement for XML, I'd encourage you to use JSON. It's lighter weight across the network and easier to format/parse on both sides.

Comment: Have you checked that "elementName" is valid? (i.e. not null)

Comment: You start parsing your XML before having allocated your "oneam" array. That's why your adding object to it is ineffective.

Comment: So where should I place "oneam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];". Everywhere I've placed it seems to declare it empty or null...

Comment: place `oneam = [NSMutableArray array];` before the parsing and get rid of the `oneam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` you're re-allocating the `oneam` array AFTER the parser tries to save to it so of course `oneam` will be null.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. It did stop the null error, but is now saying that it is empty...would that mean that it is coming from the php not getting any results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you maybe have them somewhere else, but you're missing 2 methods I've always used when doing .xml parsing: foundCharacters and didEndElement.  I followed [this tutorial set](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tUxV_66Q4U&feature=related) (all 3 videos - about 40 min worth), and after using it on a couple different instances it really helped me understand how to use the NSXMLParsers.  Maybe try following his methods and see if that clears things up for you.

Comment: As I suspected, the reason for the empty value is coming from the php. Thanks for the link. It helped point me in the right direction!

Comment: ahh ok, I have no experience with php, so sorry I couldn't have been more directly helpful.  Glad you got it figured out tho.

Comment: Also, if you solved your problem in a way unrelated to the answers that have been suggested before, make sure you add your own answer and accept it so that anyone that comes along this post with a similar problem in the future will know how you fixed it.

Comment: Well, I haven't technically solved it...so I edited the question to reflect the progress. I will though when I have.

Comment: AHA! Turns out it was because I left out my params. Your tutorials helped point me in the right direction, so I am giving you the credit

Comment: Fine with me, thanks. But I'm not the guy that made the tutorial, I just pointed you to it.

Answer (score 0):

> So where should I place "oneam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];".
>   Everywhere I've placed it seems to declare it empty or null...

Whenever I use any type of array I always use lazy initialisation, so if it's null it's initialised in the getter method, like so:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)oneam
{
    if (!_oneam){
        _oneam = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return _oneam;
}
```

When I @synthesize, I make sure it's defined like:

```
@synthesize oneam = _oneam;
```

Comment: I've just tried your method too, and it also gets rid of the null error, but is returning saying that it is now empty. Does that mean that it is coming from the php above?