# Empty NSArray when it should be filled

Tags: php, ios, xml, xcode, nsarray

I have been trying to get a mysql entry into a nsarray on iOS using xml. I was getting an "empty" array from my log (though it was saying that I was downloading information from my website) and now believe that it is coming from the php below not producing a proper attribute, thereby sending nothing. However, I thought I was doing it correctly. **What am I doing wrong that it is producing an "empty" output.** The actual output in the xcode log is is {} at index 0. My original question can be found here but should not be necessary: [NSArray is empty in iOS despite mysql entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254934/nsarray-is-null-in-ios-despite-mysql-entry)

```
<?php

$login = "hello";
$dbh = new PDO('(censored)');
$sql = "SELECT oneam FROM login WHERE username = '$login'";

$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$r = $doc->createElement( "oneam" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );
foreach ( $q->fetchAll() as $row) {
    $e = $doc->createElement( "location" );

    $e->setAttribute( 'its', $row['oneam']);

    $r->appendChild( $e );

}
print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: would you please add examplenary output of `print $doc->saveXML();`?

Comment: That's the thing. There is no output even though it should be "1"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone. Turns out I forgot to put my $params in for the array. Go it working. Thanks glasz though for looking!